# safari on ipad form get methode give white page

Tags: javascript, iphone

I’m new member and not very familiar with web developing..
The purpose is to make a user interface on an industrial machine that support JavaScript, JQuery and Ajax.
With a FORM GET method I can set parameters and start a program on the machine.
The machine returns code 204
This works well when access the webpage by a PC with IE8 and IMAC safari 6.0.5.
When I access the website from a IPHONE or IPAD the parameters are send but there opens an empty white website.
Question: can this be solved in the code or is this a setting  in safari ?
This is an example from a FORM on the webpage

```
    <form action="../karel/reset_fault" method="GET" id="FORM2"name="web_demo1">
    <input type="hidden" size="45" name="SUBMIT" value="DONE">
    <input type="submit" name="B1" value="RESET-FAULT" style="width: 180px; height: 24px;">
    </form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

204 No Content

The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.

If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.

The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand the answer, when i not use a response 204 on the server the webpage don't work at all.can you clarify your answer maybe with a example ? thanks